# Как правильно задать условие если у атрибута DATA определенное значение?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно задать условие включения звука если у атрибута DATA определенное значение?
делаю так, но не работает:

```
<div id="st1" data="1"><audio id="myaudio" loop><source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis" /> </audio></div>
<script>  function gdgd(){
  var elem = document.getElementById("st1");
  var ell = elem.getAttribute('data');
    if (ell != 1) { 
document.getElementById("myaudio").play();} 
else {
document.getElementById("myaudio").pause();}</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш скрипт работает, но код вы написали в функции, которая нигде не вызывается, ее надо вызвать, вот пример:

```js
window.onload = function (){

function gdgd(){
     var elem = document.getElementById("st1");
     var ell = elem.getAttribute('data');
     if (ell != 1) { 
       alert('не равно единице');
    } else {
       alert('все-таки равно единице');
    }
 }

gdgd();

}
```

```html
<div id="st1" data="1">
  <audio id="myaudio" loop>
  <source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis" /></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: всеравно не срабатывает код при загрузке страницы, в чем проблема не пойму

Comment: все, разобрался, спасибо!

Comment: потому что код надо выполнять после загрузки контента, дописал. Ли бо разместить его ниже контента.